# Object is null when passing a string propery of very long length (Base64 String) to .Net webapi Contoller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, base64

I am getting  updateCaseHearingModel= null when its property "StrBase64" has a very long string.
We are passing StrBase64 as base64 of a file. it works for small files but fails when file size exceeds 4MB(it creates very lengthy string).

```
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateCaseHearing([FromBody]UpdateCaseHearingModel updateCaseHearingModel)
       {
                try
                {
                       //Code here
                }
       }
```

Is there any way to pass very long string(of an object) to webapi contoller in .Net.

Comment: I think you could try modify config. maxRequestLength, maxJsonLength

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is working fine but your IIS configuration has an limit of 4MB.

See -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx

Optional Int32 attribute.
Specifies the limit for the input stream buffering threshold, in KB. This limit can be used to prevent denial of service attacks that are caused, for example, by users posting large files to the server.

The default is 4096 (4 MB).